# Loop for when i exclude one element

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this variable:

```
qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz = 2
```

and i have this array:

```
  idQuestoesUnidadeLivro = [3,4,50]

  for (let k = 0; k < qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz; k++) {
    pergunta = await this.getPerguntaAleatoria(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro) // here i get one object
    if (pergunta.rows[0].type_answer === 'Multipla Escolha') { // is entering in this if
      optionCorreta = await this.getOptionCorreta(pergunta.rows[0].id)
      if(!optionCorreta.rows[0]){ //also entering here
       for(let i_find = 0; i_find < idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.length; i_find++){
        if(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro[i_find] === pergunta.rows[0].id){ //is entering here and excluding the idQuestoesUnidadeLivro[i_find] that is equal to pergunta.rows[0].id
         idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.splice(i_find,1)
         qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz--;
         break; //don't continue the for of i_find
        }
       }
       return
      }
      // Continue the process if don't enter in the condition if(!optionCorreta.rows[0])
      optionsPergunta.push(optionCorreta.rows[0])
      ...
```

When i'm excluding one item of my array `idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.splice(i_find,1))` i need to stop the for (because i find the element that i need to exclude), if the condition is `true`, this element don't have appear again in the first for(), so i `splice()` and i decrement 1 to avoid loop.

If the element is excluded, i need to return to the start of the first `for()`.

My problem is when my condition enter in the `if(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro[i_find] === pergunta.rows[0].id)` the for entering in eternal loop and i can't find why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `return` command after if.

It could finish your function by `return`.

And update break to the below.

```
OUTER_LOOP: for (let k = 0; k < qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz; k++) {
...
 qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz--;
         break OUTER_LOOP; //don't continue the for of i_find
```

Comment: if i remove the return is doing the optionsPergunta.push(perguta.rows[0].id) and this element is undefined

Comment: I can't break the first for(), only if qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz === k.

Comment: the second for() haves to break when i exclude one element and haves to return to the start of the first for() if k is < than qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz

Comment: break OUTER_LOOP; is not break first for loop. It's only for second for loop.

Comment: you defined the OUTER_LOOP as the first loop, so when i break is breaking the first for() i changed to break the second for: OUTER_LOOP: for(let i_find = 0; i_find < idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.length; i_find++){ but my problem is when i have to return in if(!optionCorreta.rows[0]){ if entering in this i have to return of the start of the first for() but when i return i'm getting infinite loop

Comment: Yes. So the problem is that there is matched condition with your if statement. But it's returned by `break` and loop again. This is the reason of infinite loop.
So try to update codebase with break label;

Answer (score 0):

try using a flag for control push line

```
idQuestoesUnidadeLivro = [3,4,50]
let mustPushOptionCorreta = true;//***
let addedPerguntasGerarQuiz = 0;

for (let k = idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.length - 1; k >= 0 && addedPerguntasGerarQuiz < qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz; k--) {
pergunta = await this.getPerguntaAleatoria(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro) // here i get one object
if (pergunta.rows[0].type_answer === 'Multipla Escolha') { // is entering in this if
    mustPushOptionCorreta = true;//***
  optionCorreta = await this.getOptionCorreta(pergunta.rows[0].id)
  if(!optionCorreta.rows[0]){ //also entering here
   for(let i_find = 0; i_find < idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.length; i_find++){
    if(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro[i_find] === pergunta.rows[0].id){ //is entering here and excluding the idQuestoesUnidadeLivro[i_find] that is equal to pergunta.rows[0].id
     idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.splice(i_find,1)
     qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz--;//I guess you should remove this line
     mustPushOptionCorreta = false
     break; //don't continue the for of i_find
    }
   }

}
// Continue the process if don't enter in the condition if(!optionCorreta.rows[0])
if(mustPushOptionCorreta) {//***
      optionsPergunta.push(optionCorreta.rows[0])
      addedPerguntasGerarQuiz++
```

If I guess right, you want create a quiz with `qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz` questions in it. Why when you select an inappropriate question, reduce `qtdPerguntasGerarQuiz`?

Comment: I try this but my for() don't continue when the element is removed. i try changed the for to while: while(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro.length){ but when the condition enter in the if that splice, the while condition stop, i don't know why

Comment: When you have a for loop in an array and in the loop you are remove some items from the array, you should use count down counter in the for condition. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when the condition `!optionCorreta.rows[0]` meets, then the function ends, no matter what any other condition check or the `splice` action happens.
So let's try to refactor your code by removing the `return` statement:

```
for(    ) {
    if( !optionCorreta.rows[0] ) {

        ....
        for(     ) {

           if(   ) {
              splice()
              break;
           }

    } else {
        optionsPergunta.push(optionCorreta.rows[0]); 
    }
}
```

In this way when the break statement reaches, it exits the inner loop. Now since the other lines are inside the `else`, then it gets back to start of the first loop.

In the case of *infinite loop*, did you step through your code in the node debugger? There may be problems with `getPerguntaAleatoria(idQuestoesUnidadeLivro)` or `getOptionCorreta(pergunta.rows[0].id)` methods.